# Attempt to search for a specific string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to find a specific row in the database based on the user's message, namely: `catalystname`.

Within the schema I have successfully indexed the given string as text:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const scheduleMessageSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: Schema.Types.Oid, auto: true },
    catalystname: String,
    catalystdesc: String,
    catalystquest: String,
    date: String,
});

scheduleMessageSchema.index({catalystname: 'text'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('dbcatalyst', scheduleMessageSchema);
```

My search code:

```
const Catal = require("../src/models/dbcatalyst.js")


module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    message.content = args.slice(0).join(" ")


        Catal.find({$text: {$search: message.content}})
        .exec(function(docs){

        let embedlogs3 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`1`, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setDescription(`${docs}`)
            .setColor("#33ffff")

        message.channel.send(embedlogs3)
        /*/ ${collected.first().content}/*/
    });


}
```

And started searching for the required line in the message. The bot successfully copes with its task, but displays the entire document in full instead of 1 line.

```
_id: 5e243704961eb23c106bfb02,
catalystname: 'Чёрный Коготь',
catalystdesc: '0',
catalystquest: '0',
date: '1579430157018',
__v: 0
}
```

Can I somehow output exactly the string? `catalystname`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried using `docs.catalystname`?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell `TypeError: Cannot read property 'catalystname' of null`

Comment: What is `docs`? Is it an object or an array?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell object, probably.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Mongoose documentation, it seems the callback takes **two** parameters:

1. `err` An error or null
2. `docs` The returned document(s)

Change your callback to

```js
Catal.find({$text: {$search: message.content}})
  .exec(function(err, docs){
    ...
  });
```

and you should receive an array of matching documents.

Comment: That's right, I got the necessary array, but now I need to find the string `catalystname` from this array. I tried to do this `docs.catalystname`, but the console throws an error: `(node:8904) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.` , and the output: `undefined`

Comment: You're looking for `docs[index].catalystname` with `index` being the index of the item you are looking for (in this case probably `0`)

Comment: `docs['text'].catalystname` right? I just don't really understand how it works.

Comment: You might want to learn the fundamentals first before diving in and creating a bot: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array